# Keeping VH and VW rules when on-screen keyboard is active

Tags: android, html, css, ios

I have an issue (that is obviously still commonplace for many folks) where the on-screen keyboard on most smaller mobile devices kills all of my page content because each section calculates viewport height with subtraction of static headers.

I tried to start a fix with this:

```
$(function() {
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    $("html, body").css({"width":w,"height":h});
});
```

but I think the true issue is that I'd rather just keep the viewport the same, as if it were ignoring the onscreen keyboard completely. As of now, the keyboard makes the viewport so small (~400 x ~400) that my content is all just squished on top of one another.

Before I go through and make new rules for each section when the keyboard is active, is there a better universal solution to just treat the viewport the same and essentially ignore the keyboard being part of the viewport?

Comment: You could write your css in such a way that elements have a minimum height. Meaning that even if your user makes the viewport short (like by opening the keyboard) it wont shrink to unacceptable levels. Use min-height.

Comment: Can you share some more code which demonstrates how you are sizing your body? What is your viewport meta tag? And are you using `vh` and `vw` units? If so, did you have a look at the recent rework of the viewport units? [Relative length units based on viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport)?

Comment: @WillD min-height is definitely one of the next steps I was thinking of employing for sure, thanks!

Comment: @Andy I am using vh and vw but I wasn't aware of the rework so I'll have to check into that. The javascript I shared is all I've sued currently as far as sizing the body and the viewport meta tag is ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">```